# MSBuild community error when try to check out svn

Tags: svn, msbuild

It seems the MSbuild has not a lot of good documentation about how to checkout project from svn and store it and build it, I download the MSbuild community and not sure where is in the code I'm doing wrong. Here is my code sample

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project DefaultTargets="Build" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

        <Import Project=
          "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

        <Target Name="GetSource">
                <Message Text="Checking out trunk into $(SourceDirectory)" />
                <SvnCheckout RepositoryPath="https://server/svn/project" 
                    LocalPath="C:\TestForm\TestSVN"
                    UserName="myUserName"
                    Password="myPassword">
                    <Output TaskParameter="Revision" PropertyName="Revision" />
                </SvnCheckout>
                <Message Text="Have got revision: $(Revision)"/>
            </Target>

        <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="GetSource;" />

    </Project>
```

I'm getting error when I call from the command line "msbuild"

here is what the error look like

```
 c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018: The "S
    vnCheckout" task failed unexpectedly.\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018: System
    .Exception: Could not find svn.exe.  Looked in PATH locations and various commo
    n folders inside Program Files.\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018:    at
    MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Subversion.SvnClient.FindToolPath(String toolName)\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018:    at
    MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Subversion.SvnClient.GenerateFullPathToTool()\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018:    at
    Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ComputePathToTool()\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018:    at
    Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.Execute()\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018:    at
    MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Subversion.SvnClient.Execute()\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018:    at
    Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutio
    nHost.Execute()\r
    c:\TestForm\LoadSVN.csproj(10,13): error MSB4018:    at
    Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that caused the issue. When installing SVN make sure you have check the command line option to be installed it is unchecked by default, this cause to not install svn.exe which caused the error